# Add some extra configuration to beans defined in Spring starters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

### TL;DR

What is the best way to add some configuration to already created beans, e.g. to bean created by `Spring Auto Configuration` mechanism?

---

### UseCase

I'm trying to configure a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` in a best possible way. I tried to create a new instance of that object in my `MvcConfiguration` class, and configure everything in that place. It worked, but I was thinking about something more elegant.

And I found a `WebMvcAutoConfiguration`, with `viewResolver(BeanFactory beanFactory)` method, that creates a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` bean. I decided I would like to use this, since it's better to use existing code, than duplicate it.

But how can I add some more configuration to that bean? I tried with something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver;

    @Autowired
    private ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver;

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver jsonViewResolver() {
        return new JsonViewResolver();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setViewResolvers(Arrays.asList(jsonViewResolver(), thymeleafViewResolver));
    }
}
```

and configure everything in `@PostConstruct` method but I wonder, if it is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Autowiring by constructor.

```
        @Configuration
        public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


            private ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver;

            private ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver;

           @Autowired
           public MvcConfiguration(ContentNegotiatingViewResolver  contentNegotiatingViewResolver,ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver){

             this.contentNegotiatingViewResolver=contentNegotiatingViewResolver;
             this.thymeleafViewResolver=thymeleafViewResolver;
             ViewResolver jsonViewResolver= new JsonViewResolver();
             this.contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setViewResolvers(Arrays.asList(jsonViewResolver, thymeleafViewResolver));

        }




  }
```

Alternate solution :

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {



        @Override
        public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {

            registry.enableContentNegotiation();
            registry.viewResolver(jsonViewResolver());
            super.configureViewResolvers(registry );
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am not getting the error, could you please post the error.

Comment: I'm using version of Spring boot > 1.4, so it's actually a error message. The problem is, that I extend a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. Probably, `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` depends on `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and my implementation of that class, depends on  `WebMvcAutoConfiguration`. After i removed an extend, error disappeared

Comment: Unfortunatelly, beans that need to be autowired, are loaded after those methods. But i really like that configureViewResolvers. I'll try to put viewResolver registry to another configuration class, maybe it will solve the problem.